# extending scala collections for a specific member type

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I want to do something like

```
class Pack extends collection.immutable.List[Dog]{
  def pullSled() = //...
}
```

But the Scala compiler tells me

```
illegal inheritance from sealed class List
```

This would be trivial to do in Java, but I think there is something key I am missing.

**Motivations:**

I want to be able to use all the base class methods

```
(new Pack()).contains(snoopy)
```

I want to be able to extend it, either directly or with mixins

```
new Pack() with Driver
```

I would like to be able to change the underlying collection type simply (to switch to a Set for instance)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`List[T]` is final, hence you cannot extend from it (see why below). If you just need an additional method on a `List[Dog]`, easiest is probably to pimp it:

```
implicit class Pack(l: List[Dog]) {
  def pullSled() = //...
}
```

If `Pack` is in scope, the following will work:

```
val a = List(new Dog)
a.pullSled()
```

If you really need to create your own collection of dogs, have a look here:
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html

You cannot extend from `List[T]` because of the following: Suppose you have `Pack` as you would like to have it, now the following will work, but not really give you what you want:

```
val pack: Pack = ...

val pack2 = new Dog :: pack

// pack2: List[Dog], not a Pack... :(
```

Properly extending from `LinearSeq` as described in the upper link will mitigate this.

Comment: Good answer! Part of my motivation for this is readability.  I still want all the useful methods of a collection, but still be able to pass around simple unparamiterized objects.  In real life I want to do this for much more cumbersome classes then dog. Thanks again!

Comment: @user833970 Glad it helps. A simple type alias might be an option too, by the way.

Comment: The problem with ailiasing is that I still cannot extend my specialized class later.

Comment: Sure, that would be just to have less name clutter. Btw. a fourth option would be to use composition and proxy only the stuff you need, maybe with an implicit conversion to `List[Dog]` that extracts the inner container.